# Revslider stuck on first image

Tags: jquery, html, slider, bxslider

I've placed a Themepunch Banner Revslider with three images in the hero of a client's site. In the first loop, the first image gets stuck between transitions. However, if you manually click to the next image, upon the next loop the slider will play through without any errors.

It is unclear why it is stopping on the first slide, I've played around with the parameters (located in the bottom script on the home page).

You can check it out for yourself [here](http://vegastudios.ca/staging/courtland-pm/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it's hanging like that; however, you can get around it by using jquery to trigger a click event on the next element.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.tp-bullets .bullet:nth-child(2)').trigger('click');
},7250);
```

Add this code after slider initiation, inside the $(document).ready() function.

Let me know if you have any questions.